# PHP mysqli_query not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

I have a foreach loop which runs through an array of table names in a MySQL database and then does a mysqli query to re-index the table.

The query and loop both seem to work fine, however after a certain number of tables the query stops working.

If I simply echo each table name then it will display all of them so I know it isn't missing out tables in the loop, and I can see that the first few tables are getting correctly reindexed. It seems to stop working after around 50 tables.

Here is the loop:

```
foreach($tables as $table) {
    mysqli_multi_query($connect, "SET @newid=0; UPDATE $table SET ID=(@newid:=@newid+1) ORDER BY ID;");
}
```

What might be causing it top stop working, is mysql timing out or breaking the operation because so many queries are being run in quick succession? Something else?

Using mysqli_error I get:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: What do you mean with 'stops working'? Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, but in the later tables in the array the ID's don't reset to 1,2,3 etc. They stay at say 1,2,5,8

Comment: @brain99 I have updated my post with an error message

Comment: These two resources might give you a different idea about how you go about this, rather than using multiple query statements.  [MySQL Manual - Rebuilding or Repairing Tables or Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html) and [how to reindex mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089492/how-to-reindex-mysql-table).  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I've seen this error before it's because a MySQL query has returned multiple result sets and some of these are still unfetched. This is also common when using stored procedures. To diagnose this problem is the cause you could put a line like the following at the end of your loop to ensure any pending results sets are fetched before trying to run another query:

```
while(mysqli_more_results($Conn)) mysqli_next_result($Conn);
```

(Remember to change the connection `$Conn` to whatever yours is called). Here are a couple of links to further information and examples.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.more-results.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_next_result.asp

Regards,

James